# What was the fate of the Shiloh Launch Complex at Canaveral

Tags: launch-site, cape-canaveral

Living near Canaveral, since 2013 (that I know of) much has gone back and forth about the proposed Shiloh Launch Complex in the former citrus groves within the north side of the Cape Canaveral Spaceport Masterplan.  Much went back and forth with the FAA and other environmental interests.

**What was the result / replacement option / fate of the vertical launch pads proposed at Shiloh?**